# How to get symbol of pressed key IE8-?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (!event) {
        event = window.event;
    } 
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

   console.log(event);
   console.log(keyCode);
}
```

This works in IE8 browser. But, I still need to know the symbol of the pressed key.
In newer browsers, I can use "e.key". I tried to output event to the console, but I didn't find anything similar to the symbol of the pressed key. How do I solve this?

Comment: IE8? You mean Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: Yes, i need to do it for IE8 (and earlier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has been found. This code works even in IE5 (checked on the Emulator).

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (!event) {
    event = window.event;
  } 
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  var pressedKeySymbol = event.key || String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase();
  console.log(event);
  console.log(keyCode);
}
```

Thank very much to Valerii from the glorious island of Sakhalin.